# Secure file transfer launched from php file

Tags: python, php

I am working on a developing a website. The website asks the user to provide some files. Based on these files, calculations are made and a result is sent back to the user. I would like to run the calculation on another machine (core of computation). Therefore, the web server must transfer the files uploaded by the user to this other machine in order for a C program that do the calculation to be run on that machine. 
I tried writting a python script that transfer files perfectly when executed from root of the web server. Trying to execute it from a php script, this gives a "permission denied" problem.
Can someone suggest an idea that works?

Comment: You will need to provide more details.  What exactly is giving the *permission denied* message?

Comment: The permission denied message is because that the Apache web server does not have the same permissions as the root.

Comment: And it shouldn't have, but what is it trying to do when you get the error, is it just trying to read a file or run the C program?

Comment: I think it is normal that the  permission is denied. But i couldn't find another solution to do so. In fact, i am just trying to transfer the files to the core of the calculation(another machine) when a html form is submitted.